# <ng-select>:MouseEvent.target.select() is not working when fire element.nativeElement.click()

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngselect

I am not understanding why with mouseclick event `ng-select` dropdown input text is getting selected but while doing `this.elementRef.nativeElement.click()` not getting selected input text.([image])

1.working one

```
<ng-select (click)="onClick($event)"></ng-select>
```

2.Not working

```
constructor(public element:ElementRef){}

triggetClickEvent(){
   this.element.nativeElement.click();
}
```

click event method:

```
onClick($event){
   $event.target.select();//while triggetClickEvent exception:$event.target.select is not a function
}
```

Any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument `$event` is a `MouseEvent` and `onClick` method is called after you click on dropdown not before that.

Changes to be done:

1.Add id, local ref and open event handler function.

```
<ng-select id="element" #element (open)="onOpen()"...></ng-select>
```

2.Use `ViewChild` to get element reference.

```
@ViewChild('element') element;
```

3.code inside `triggetClickEvent()` and `onOpen()` functions.

```
triggetClickEvent(){
   let el = document.getElementById("element");
   el.classList.add("customCSSClass");
   this.element.focus();
}

onOpen() {
    let el = document.getElementById("element");
    el.classList.remove("customCSSClass");
}
```

Note: I know it is not good practice to directly access DOM and I tried to use Renderer2 but `focus` event is not working with it somehow.

3.Add below css [Refer Custom styles section of ng-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select#custom-styles)

```
.ng-select.ng-select-focused.customCSSClass  ::ng-deep .ng-value { 
    background-color: blue;
}
.ng-select.ng-select-focused.customCSSClass ::ng-deep .ng-placeholder { 
    background-color: blue ;
}
```

[You can find working code snippet here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-owcd6e)

Comment: Thanks for reply @srp. I want to select/highlight text as per image provided above without open dropdown...i don't want to bind any option, just whatever selected option is present in input combobox that want show as selected

Comment: @r08 I have updated my answer. I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: @JohnPeters it is not clear for me any refrence link could u provide....

Comment: @srp text selection is not possible?...in above problem is on click also focus..so if i entering value that time also showing background color...how to prevent this one selection should be happen at very first time focus after that it should be normal.

Comment: @r08 Always be specific about what you are looking for in the beginning itself and also put some code blocks(e.g stackblitz) if possible as it will be helpful to understand better.I have updated my answer. Hope this is what you are looking for.